# Mostrar información dependiendo del producto clickeado - React.js

Tags: reactjs

estoy aprendiendo React y estoy haciendo la sgte [app](https://husdady.github.io/simulador-de-compras/) , necesito mostrar la información del celular del cual se esta clickeando. Al hacer click en la imagen de un celular me genera una ventana modal, bien ahora la informacion la uso del sgte [json](https://github.com/Husdady/simulador-de-compras/tree/main/json), Entonces deseo hacer que dependiendo de la imagen clickeado me muestre esa informacion.

Ejm: el celular Samsung Galaxy A20 en el json esta la posicion 0 y el Zte Blade A5 en la 2, dependiendo de su posicion me debe mostrar su informacion, espero pueda entender lo que intento hacer. A continuación el componente donde renderizo la ventana modal:

```js
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import Icon from '../assets/Icon';
import './css/information-products.css';
import celulares from '../../json/celulares';

class InformationProduct extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Fragment>
        <Icon iconName="fas fa-window-close" id="close-modal" onClick={() => this.props.showModal(false)} />
        <div className="wrap">
          <div className="information-product">
            <figure>
              <img loading="lazy" src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/${celulares[this.props.i].imagen}`} alt={'mayita'} title={'mayita'} />
            </figure>
            <h3>Modelo:<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;{celulares[this.props.i].modelo}</span></h3>
            <h3>Marca:<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;{celulares[this.props.i].marca}</span></h3>
            <h3>Memoria RAM:<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;{celulares[this.props.i].ram}</span></h3>
            <h3>Batería:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>{celulares[this.props.i].bateria}</span>&nbsp;<span>mAh</span></h3>
            <h3>Camara Frontal:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>{celulares[this.props.i].camara}</span>&nbsp;<span>MP</span></h3>
            <h3>Resolución:<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;{celulares[this.props.i].resolucion}</span></h3>
            <h3>Precio:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>$/.</span>&nbsp;<span>{celulares[this.props.i].precio}</span></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default InformationProduct;
```

Ahora en el componente que renderiza al anterior, en este genero un estado de un numero -1 que cada vez que se hace click en la imagen aumenta en 1:

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import InformationProduct from './InformationProduct';

class App extends Component{

  state = {
    position: -1,
  }

  /* */
  increase = () =>{
    this.setState({
      position: this.state.position + 1
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
        {this.state.showModal === true ? <InformationProduct i={this.state.position} /> : null}
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

No he puesto el componente completo, pues deseo que sea más facil de leer, practicamente en la propiedad i del componente `<InformationProduct />` cambio el stado de position, pero creo que esto es una mala practica, ya que no me mostrara la informacion dependiendo de la imagen del producto clickeado.

Ya que cuando se haga click en cualquier imagen la propiedad i tomara el valor de 0, por lo que siempre mostrara Samsung Galaxy A20, por lo que debo mostrar la informacion dependiendo de la imagen clickeada, [aqui](https://github.com/Husdady/simulador-de-compras) pueden ver los componentes, Gracias!

Comment: Creo que estas abordando mal la situación. El componente modal ya lo tienes, por lo que sólo deberías enviar el index del elemento clickeado, no crear una variable posición, es innecesario.. puedes incluir la forma en que estás renderizando los celulares?

Comment: Paulo, pude resolver el problema hace unas horas, igual gracias por contestar !

Comment: Excelente! No olvides incluir la solución que encontraste para futuras referencias. Saludos!

Comment: La solución esta en los componentes del github que menciono haya arriba, bueno ahora tengo que hacer la parte más 'dificil' de agregar productos al carrito, tal vez si no puedo resolverlo, formulare otra pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes pasar funciones como propiedades a tus componentes, además de configurar algunas propiedades en el objeto `state` para controlar cuándo se muestra el modal de un celular y pasar su `id`.

Hay 3 componentes que necesitan configuración:

- App
- Product
- InformationProduct

---

#### App

Se modifica el constructor, agregando las siguientes propiedades `productIndex` y `infoVisible`, también se registran con `bind` los métodos `showModal` y `hideModal`:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allProducts: celulares,
      categoryCheckboxes: [...objects],
      productVisible: true,
      productIndex:0,
      infoVisible:false,
      activeFilter: []
    }
    this.onFilterChange = this.onFilterChange.bind(this);
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
  }
```

Luego, `showModal` y `hideModal` se codifican como métodos de la clase `App`, los cuales se van a comunicar con los componentes `Product` e `InformationProduct`:

```
  showModal(productId){
    this.setState({
      infoVisible: true,
      productIndex:productId
    })
  }
    
  hideModal(){
     this.setState({
       infoVisible: false
    })
  }
```

Después, se codifica un ternary operator anidado, esto con la finalidad de mostrar `Products` o `InformationProducts`, nótese que los curly braces que usa la expresión del ternary anidado se omiten:

```
<section className="products">
            {(!this.state.infoVisible) ? 
              this.state.productVisible ? this.state.activeFilter.map( x =>{
              return (
                <Product key={x.id}
                imagen={x.imagen} modelo={x.modelo} stock={x.stock} precio={x.precio} showModal={this.showModal} id={x.id} />
                )
              })
              : <NotFound text="Ninguna casilla ha sido marcada..." />
            
            :<InformationProduct hideModal={this.hideModal} i={this.state.productIndex}/>}
</section>
```

Aquí mismo, se pasan nuevas `props` para el componente `Product`, el método `showModal` y `id`:

```
<Product ...props showModal={this.showModal} id={x.id} />
```

Nótese que en el código original (repo de github), se pasa el `id` en la prop `key`, pero aquí se pasa explícitamente como otra propiedad, ver [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Finalmente, para terminar la configuración del componente `App`, se pasan `props` para el componente `InformationProduct`, el método `hideModal` y `productIndex`:

```
<InformationProduct hideModal={this.hideModal} i={this.state.productIndex}/>
```

---

#### Product

Se recíbe el método `showModal` desde el componente `App`, para poder utilizarlo con un evento `onClick`, esto dentro del `div` que envuelve la estructura de cada elemento de la lista celulares; cuando el usuario de un click a un celular de la lista, se pasará su `id` con el método `showModal`:

```
return (
      <div className="product" onClick={()=>this.props.showModal(id)}>
         //...codigo
      </div>
    )
```

---

#### Information Product

Se recíbe el método `hideModal` desde el componente `App`, para poder utilizarlo con un evento `onClick` dentro de `Icon` que parece ser el icono de cierre:

```
return(
      <Fragment>
        <Icon iconName="fas fa-window-close" id="close-modal" onClick={this.props.hideModal} />
       //...codigo
      </Fragment>
    )
```

---

#### Notas de campo:

-Los métodos `showModal` y `hideModal` junto con ternary operator, manejan banderas tipo `boolean`, tal y como las has venido manejando en otras partes de tu app.

-Es un diseño parecido a lo que estas proponiendo, puedes incluso tratar de adaptarlo. Lo importante aquí es como se pasan los métodos y los parametros como el `id` del producto.

-Los siguientes cambios, son con el propósito de que puedas continuar con tu diseño original, mientras sigas con tu investigación de react podrás mejorar la app.

-Parece que la versión de tu repo de github, no esta sincronizada con tu [demo live](https://husdady.github.io/simulador-de-compras/), así que solo acople el componente `InformationProduct`, desde aquí.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Tomaré tu respuesta como correcta por si le pueda servir a alguien más, además tomaré en cuenta todo lo que escribes en tu respuesta, me será de ayuda, gracias!

Comment: La demo se ve bastante bien, saludos!